# Sum of time to deteriorate shielded cells

Tags: algorithm

Problem: on each turn cells decrease by 1 if a neighbor (top/bottom/left/right) is zero. What is the sum of the time for each cell to reach zero?

Is there a faster solution than to use a priority queue?

Is there a name for this problem or a similar problem? I don’t know what to search for.

Example, answer is 7 and comes from counting the number of non-zero cells every turn and adding them up.

```
00000
00100
01210
00100
00000
```

Initially there are 5 non zero cells.

```
00000
00000
00200
00000
00000
```

After first turn, 1 non zero cell.

```
00000
00000
00100
00000
00000
```

After second turn, 1 non zero cell.

```
00000
00000
00000
00000
00000
```

After third turn, 0 non zero cell.

**Update:** A comment suggests fast marching. Would it work in this example, answer is 10.

```
00000
00200
02220
00100
00000
```

Initially there are 5 non zero cells.

```
00000
00100
01210
00000
00000
```

After first turn, 4 non zero cell.

```
00000
00000
00100
00000
00000
```

After second turn, 1 non zero cell.

```
00000
00000
00000
00000
00000
```

After third turn, 0 non zero cell.

Comment: If this is in the context of the `Game of Life`, or similar, you should state that in the question.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError The question does contain a complete context-free problem statement, albeit a short one.

Comment: "Is there a faster solution than to use a priority queue?" - It depends. How are you using the priority queue?

Comment: Hint: A first step could be to determine a way to compute the number of steps a cell with the number `a` will remain 'non-zero'. If it has a zero neighbor, then it will remain non-zero for `a` steps. Otherwise, it will remain non-zero for `a+b` steps, with `b` the min 'non-zero steps' among its neighbors.

Comment: See [fast marching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_marching_method#Algorithm).